# Problema al insertar un registro con imagen en Django 3

Tags: django, django-models

Tengo una Aplicación de recetas de cocina en Django 3. En un principio armé el modelo de sin tener en cuenta una imagen. Hice todo el CRUD correspondiente y todo perfecto. Podía crear, editar, borrar. Después se me ocurrió agregarle una imagen, por lo tanto modifiqué el modelo y me puse a reacomodar el código. El resultado funcionó a medias, ya que cuando quiero crear un registro y elijo una imagen, Django se queja y me arroja un error. En cambio, si creo el registro SIN IMAGEN, el registro se crea, perfectamente. Cuando lo edito y le agrego una imagen, la incorpora perfectamente. Por lo tanto no se que es lo que está pasando.
El modelo es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Luego el error que me arroja es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El archivo forms.py tiene lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
este es el formulario de creación del registro
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
alguna sugerencia ?
desde ya muchas gracias !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es tu función `custom_upload_to`, el error sucede porque aun no se a guardado la instancia que se esta creando en la db, como consecuencia no se puede obtener la instancia (lo cual, se levanta la excepción) y también no se puede borrar ninguna imagen, evidentemente.

Ademas de que este error, siempre sucederá al momento de **crear un instancia del modelo `Recipe`**.

Entonces tu función debería ser así:

```
def custom_upload_to(instance, filename):
    try:
        old_instance = Recipe.objects.get(pk = instance.pk)
        old_instance.image.delete()
    except Recipe.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    return 'recipes/' + filename
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Es verdad !!!... cómo se me pasó ese detalle !!! Un millón de gracias !!! Ahora anda perfecto !!!

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte xd